# insert Enum value in param action

Tags: java, struts2, enums

I'm trying to set an Enum value to the Following action

```
<action name="actionOne" class="SomeClass">
    <param name="myValue">@some.package.Enum@VALUE</param>
    <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

but when debugging it, it shows **myValue**:

```
null
```

.

myValue corresponds to a private object with its public **getter** and **setter**.
Is it possible to do this? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For that you need to configure Static Parameters Interceptor. You need to enable parsing of static parameters and exclude them from the request parameters map. Also wrap your parameter value in `${...}` in order to evaluate it.

```
<action name="actionOne" class="SomeClass">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="staticParams.parse">true</param>
    <param name="staticParams.merge">false</param>
  </interceptor-ref>

  <param name="myValue">${@some.package.Enum@VALUE}</param>

  <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I ended up putting the Literal values, without the class name and actually worked